# How to populate a jsf table from a managed bean while using adf business components?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am new to ADF and it seems I am missing something. I am using the Oracle HR database. I am using Business Components as the Model. I have ViewObjects for Country, Location and Department. As well as ViewLinks by FK between Country-Location and Location-Department. I exposed a DataControl Country-> Location -> Deperatments.

So now I can build a JSF with three areas in which each is shown. If I click on a country I get the locations. If I then click on location I get the departments. That works.

But I want to show only Country and Departments. So I implemented a managed bean to make use of the iterators and populate the department table throught that bean, by binding it to the value attribute of the table. But I only have Row objects to return and due to use of BC no Class definitions which I could map my rows back to objects.

So how can I just show all Departments in a Country? What is the ADF way to do this?

My managed bean:

```
public class CountryDepartmensBean {

public CountryDepartmensBean() {
    super();
}

private ArrayList<Row> populate;

public ArrayList<Row> getPopulate() {
    DCBindingContainer bindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding countriesView1Iterator = bindings.findIteratorBinding("CountriesView1Iterator");

    DCIteratorBinding locationsView2Iterator = bindings.findIteratorBinding("LocationsView2Iterator");
    DCIteratorBinding departmentsView3Iterator = bindings.findIteratorBinding("DepartmentsView3Iterator");
    Row[] locations =  locationsView2Iterator.getAllRowsInRange();
    ArrayList<Row> employees = new ArrayList<Row>();
    for(int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        locationsView2Iterator.setCurrentRowIndexInRange(i);
        departments.addAll(Arrays.asList(departmentsView3Iterator.getAllRowsInRange()));
    }

    return departments;
}

public void setPopulate(Row[] rows){

}
}
```

the getPopulate Method is called and returns the rows that I want, but returing rows seems to be the wrong way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using managed bean for this case is a wrong way itself.
All you need is to create viewObject that will match your expectation.
Create a viewObject joining Location + Department tables. Make it child to Country viewObject through viewLink.
 Now you can drag&drop master-detail tables on the page.

Comment: Can I take from that that in ADF if possible use new ViewObjects instead of managedbeans if possible?

Comment: @Tarken beans are meant to support view rendering, not to generate or provide data. So all your data should reside in model if possible.

Comment: as I understood it it is the purpose of some of the beans to manipulate/check/etc. data. And the data is still provided by the model and I am using the model to get the data. I am just trying to learn the ADF way.

Comment: @Tarken Manipulation and checks also better leave for model. View is for representation and bean is to help with it, like hiding/showing some of data or providing server side support for controls, converting data to other formats and so on. You can [read more about MVC pattern here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really)